# Minimizing downtime during MariaDB Replication Setup

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I have the task of setting up MariaDB (10.0) replication from a master running in a datacenter to a slave running out in an AWS VPC. Reading up on the instructions on [Setting Up Replication - MariaDB Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/setting-up-replication/) there's mention of taking a lock on all tables on the master (`FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`) while using mysqldump to transfer the Databases across to the slave. This step has me concerned a slight bit for the following reasons

1. We have a number of large databases (~20 DBs @ 40G) with some huge ones (~3 @ 100G).
2. It takes about ~40 minutes to transfer each DB across to the slave. In total, this entire process could take up to `20` hours (assuming good conditions).
3. We can't keep locks on the master for too long - as we disrupt business while the tables are locked.
4. Should anything fail in the process of copying the dumps across to the slave - we'll have taken the master down in vain and may need to attempt this again.

What would be a good way to go about setting up replication in this scenario with minimal downtime to production. I'm open to some out of the box thinking - is there a way to do this by breaking things down and doing them in stages so that we can verify each stage?

**EDIT**
I should add that we do take nightly dumps of the DBs as part of the backup strategy. Perhaps there's a way of using these to aid the process?

Answer (score 1):

Backing up with mysqldump is a slow process. Use a backup tool like Mariabackup/Xtrabackup. It takes physical backup of all data. It can take hot backups, so no locking or downtime would be needed.

[Mariabackup](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariabackup-overview/)

[Xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/alestic/ec2-consistent-snapshot of your EBS volume using --mysql-master-status-file FILE option.

Create a new volume from that snapshot and attach to new instance or another instance you can use to copy to a remote location if needed.. The db server will only be locked for a couple seconds. I just performed this operation on a server with a 2TB server with millions of tables.

Start the slave db with data files from other server reset the slave and change your master with the correct log position.